# Android: ListView background for each row-item

Tags: android, list, listview

I have the following ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:divider="@drawable/line"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg"/>
```

But I want to set the background for each row-item. When I set the android:background property, I change the background of the whole list and not just of each row.

How can I set the drawable background for each item in the row? I have tried everything. The only thing I can change is the android:divider drawable shown between the rows.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: create xml file for a list row and inflate that xml file in you listview adapter class

Comment: You cant directly give each row different color from the xml file...You have to create xml for your row and write conditions for background color of row  while inflating your row xml

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify a costum view layout for your rows, like a LinearLayout or so.
in this layout you specify the background color or image or what ever.

later in your list adapter in the getView() function you load this layout with
the layout inflater and returbn this view.

Answer (score 0):

```
*Use Custom Adapter.

First create Custom Adapter class and set this to fill listView

ex: 

class CusAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {

  private Context mContext;

  public ImageAdapter(Context c)
  {

   mContext = c;

  }

  public int getCount()

  {

   return 10;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position)

  {

   return null;

  }

  public long getItemId(int position)
  {

   return 0;

  }

  // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {

           //create a layout for listView

           LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

       lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

       lLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
           LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,

       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


         //check position and set background

            if(position%2==0)
            {

                   lLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.id.bckResource1);

               } 
            else

                   lLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.id.bckResource2);

        return lLayout;

   }

}

 after this set this adapter to fill listview

 listView.setAdpater(new cusAdapter(this));*
```